# Filter filenames between dots with various length

Tags: awk, sed

I have files i a dir like 
`a.b.c.d.log.1474113600`
with various length of dots between a and .log and i'd like to filter all the dots before it (maybe with sed/awk?). For example

`a.b.c.d
f.e.g
a.b`

etc. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` version:  Divide the text into parts using `.log` as delimiter, then print the very first part of the text.

```
awk -F'.log' '{NF=1}1' <<< "a.b.c.d.log.1474113600"
a.b.c.d
```

Note: Above command is same as following command:

```
awk -F'.log' '{print $1}' <<< "a.b.c.d.log.1474113600"
```

Or use variable expansion :

```
x="a.b.c.d.log.14741136100"
echo ${x%%.log*}
a.b.c.d
```

Comment: Thanks, tried 1st and works. And if I want to get timestamp also how gonna be?

Comment: No, I mean timestamp which is on the last dot of file format I describe

Comment: yes, its possible, just share how you want your output to look like . try `awk -F'.log' '{split($2,a,".");print $1 "." a[2]}' <<< "a.b.c.d.log.1474113600"`   OR `sed 's/.log//g' <<< "a.b.c.d.log.1474113600"`

Comment: No, I meant print only the timestamp.

Comment: Please provide, sample input and output.  I will try to help you.

Comment: For example, input : a.b.c.d.log. 1474113600 and output: 1474113600. A simple print [a2] in above is enough (and if possible, relatively fast for performance purposes)?

Comment: No, sorry if my fault. Tried also awk -F'.log' '{print $2}' but took .1474113600

Comment: `echo "a.b.c.d.log.1474113600" |awk -F'.log.' '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get what you want but if you mean by *files - - with various length of dots between a and .log and i'd like to filter all the dots before it* removing all dots before `.log` (which would sound reasonable to me), I'd use `perl` with negative lookbehind and lookahead for it:

```
$ echo a.b.c.d.log.1474113600 | perl -pe 's/(?<!log)\.(?!log)//g'
abcd.log.1474113600
```

ie. replace `s/` all `/g` dots `.` that aren't preceeded `(?<!log)` or followed `(?!log)` by `log` with nothing `//`.